# Stripe, send money to my customers

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments

I know how to charge cards of my customers.

BUT how can I send them money with Stripe ? I just have their card (which can be debit card or credit card).

Imagine if Uber or Lyft user stripe, how do they do to pay their drivers through stripe?

Thanks

Comment: https://stripe.com/blog/send-money-to-debit-cards

Comment: it uses recipient and it is deprecated now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*One way would be to setup a system that handles the payment and then based on the card you have pass it to 3:e party API that does money transfers or One easy way is if you ask the customers to enter in the needed information you can then use your banks API to from your account send the money to them.*

However easiest way is to use the refund function that the api of stripe has:

```
charge = await stripe.charges.refund(charge.id, {
amount: 1000
});
```

**or you you can use the create transfer function:**
https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_transfer
Create_transfer can send payments to 3:e party bank or payment service.

The thing you should base your system on is what information you will need to perform the task and then set that up once that is done you can use the already made API functions from Stripe to handle the task.

Please let me know should you have any further questions.

Comment: To create transfer, did I have to create an account for each customer? Or can I user a simple card?

Comment: You can just attach the card number that you already get from the customer.

Comment: Are you saying that I can transfer to a card directly ?

Comment: Yes you can this is how lyft does it they send "payouts to the drivers"

Comment: everything you need is in the documentation for transfer and the steps are pretty straight forward as the stripe docs are very well written.
Hope this helps!

Comment: But when I create a transfer and put my card token in 'destination' I got an error, do you know what  is my mistake?

Comment: If you check the transfer api for stripe you will see->

quote: "The id of a bank account or a card to send the transfer to, or the string". you might not be using the correct information of the card. But please note that if you read this https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_transfer you will understand how to do it.

Comment: Yes you are right, so I have to create a customer, attache my card to that customer and transfer money to this card. Thanks

Comment: I got an error : The card card_xxxxxx is not attached to this Stripe account. External accounts can only be attached to standalone Stripe accounts via the dashboard.
Do you know what's going on ? For each new customer I have to attache the card to my stripe account???

Answer (score 26):

(Disclaimer: I work for Stripe.)

Generally speaking, you can't arbitrarily send funds to third-parties through Stripe.

With [Stripe Connect](https://stripe.com/connect), you can create charges on behalf of third-parties, i.e. you'd charge a customer on behalf of a seller, and optionally take a cut (an "application fee") out of the transaction. These charges have to be for the sale of actual goods or services.

At this time, your merchants or service providers can be paid out:

- in all countries supported by Stripe: to their bank account
- in the US only: to debit cards (not credit or prepaid cards)

I recommend you spend some time reading through [Connect's documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/connect) as well as [this support article](https://support.stripe.com/questions/considerations-for-platforms-using-connect) to find out if Connect would be a good fit for your needs.

I recommend that you reach out to Stripe's support through the [contact form](https://support.stripe.com/email) and explain your business model and the flow of funds you had in mind. The support staff will be able to confirm whether your business model can be supported by Stripe and how you'd use the API to implement it.

Comment: Thank you Ywain, I am located in France and it's seems that I can't set up my account as managed so I can't connect external account to my one. Am I wrong?

Comment: At this time, managed accounts are still in private beta for French platforms. You can try writing to sales at https://stripe.com/contact/sales and explain your business model and why managed accounts would make sense for you, and you might be invited to join the beta. If you can't join the beta, you'd have to use standalone accounts, which don't let you control transfers (standalone account owners have a direct relationship transfers and choose their own transfer settings).